# Is it possible to view others' transactions in bitcoin client?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin-core, privacy

This seems like a really basic question, but I'm having trouble searching for answers on it. My understanding is that my bitcoin client (Bitcoin v0.7.1-beta) has basically theoretically downloaded the entire transaction history of every bitcoin transaction that has ever occurred. I can see my own transactions in the Transactions screen. Is there a way to see transaction with wallets that I haven't imported or created on this client? I'm just trying to get a full understanding of bitcoin technology here. Is the reason the client doesn't show transactions from other wallets due to:

1. User friendliness - it would be overwhelming to have to search through all wallet addresses when most people only care about their own (is there a way to override that?);
2. Technical limitations - it's impractical to consider every transaction in the huge database when you want to list or look up some particular piece of information;
3. Design limitations - Not every transaction is actually there with all the information necessary;
4. Privacy concerns - By making it too easy to view others' transactions people would yell out about privacy more vocally;
5. Something I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to view others' transactions

Yes.

> in bitcoin client?

No.

1. It's not terribly useful to look up the balance of somebody else's address, except maybe so they can prove they have a certain amount of funds.
2. These lookups would be *slow,* because it needs to work through millions of transactions. Creating the indexes that would allow you to do fast lookups on any bitcoin address would take a sizable amount of disk space.
3. All of them are there - it's a central part of the bitcoin protocol. What if somebody moves all of their money out of their account within a transaction you don't know about? Therefore, you have to know about all transactions, unless you want to be surprised when their payment "bounces."
4. There's already a website called [Bitcoin Block Explorer](http://blockexplorer.com/) that pretty clearly establishes that transactions are public. Even if there wasn't, you could still [build your own](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/how-do-i-access-information-on-blockexplorer-com-or-blockchain-info-without-issu/5519#5519).

Comment: Concerning #2, it sounds like you're talking about calculating a balance, but I'm not talking about looking up their balance, just looking up a transaction. For example, wouldn't it be useful to be able to use the system as a means of proving a receipt to a third party? A judge could award a case based on proof that funds were transferred from one account to another, neither of which the judge controls. Concerning #3, I'm referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#Confirmations which talks about implementations where not all transactions are stored. #4 is a good answer.

Comment: 2. It's actually quite easy to look up a transaction given its transaction ID. Use the [bitcoind rpc call `getrawtransaction`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list#Full_list) 3. Electrum clients only store their own transactions and rely on Electrum server to not lie to them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nick's answer, it's worth clarifying that even though the entire history of transactions are available, there's no information directly stating which collection of addresses belong to a particular wallet. You might get some idea of that by looking at the inputs and outputs of transactions, but there's no "wallet id" (or similar) value in the blockchain.

Comment: It has become clear(er) to me since asking the original question that there is a difference between a wallet and a bitcoin address. I was interested in determining what transactions have occurred for a particular address. I'm only now realizing/suspecting that a wallet may contain many addresses.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. New addresses are added to a wallet as created by the user. It's easier to achieve anonymity if a new address is created for each incoming transaction, if anonymity is a goal of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program in Python3 that allows you to search for any address on bitcoin core whether it belongs to your wallet or not.

Here is the github link:

https://github.com/ORP967/Bitcoin_Core_RPC_par_address

Let me know what you think or if you have any improvements you might have.