# How do I get a full transaction index with Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoind, txindex

How can I sync bitcoin full node so that I can access all details of transactions occurring on other nodes and other wallets also, like blockchain.info.

I have synced a full node using below commands, but that's giving details of node wallet account details.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
sudo apt-get install bitcoins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you have used are not for syncing to the bitcoin blockchain but to install a bitcoin, now with this client you can sync if you want, you will need days or weeks depending on your computer bandwidth and performance and 250+ giga of hard drive, you can start syncing by locating your bitcoin directoryand simply running:

> ./bitcoind

You can find more information about using and running properly a bitcoin full node here: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node

Comment: after all this command i set up my bitcoin.conf file and started bitcoin demon.but still not getting details of transaction outside of node.

Comment: ```bitcoin-cli gettransaction 03d9e448b652155061b5d06594e65cb5507a85518a6b1ae6530c6efed8377657
error code: -5
error message:
Invalid or non-wallet transaction id```

Comment: @indrajit Command `gettransaction` is for the transaction of your wallet, you can access to all transaction on bitcoin with command `getrawtransaction`, I suggest you look the documentation official of [Bitcoin corer RPC](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/)

Comment: Notice that gettransaction is for in wallet transaction, maybe you want to use getrawtransaction also you have to have txindex=1 in your conf file and need to sync the full blockchain

Comment: yes getrawtransaction is working,but how to find to address, from address and amount transacted from that .

Comment: ```getTransactionInfo(txHash) {
        var transaction = client.request("getrawtransaction", [txHash,true])
        transaction.then((details) => {
            console.log("detailsrtry", details.result);
            var decode = client.request("decoderawtransaction", [details.result.hex])
            decode.then((rrrrr)=>{
                console.log("details", rrrrr.result.vin)
                console.log("details1", rrrrr.result.vout);
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("err",err);

        })
    }```

Comment: You cannot do that with a bitcoin client, you should use https://btc.com/ see this question and the answers https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/is-it-possible-to-view-others-transactions-in-bitcoin-client

Comment: so how blockchain.info gives all details to address from address and amount of transactiom

Comment: I suppose they record every transaction from every blocks and trace every one of them, it is quite fastidious, you can build your own system for doing the same if you want https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/how-do-i-access-information-on-blockexplorer-com-or-blockchain-info-without-issu/5519#5519