# How to find the shortest unused FirstBits?

Tags: vanity-address, firstbits

I am interested in generating a bitcoin address with the shortest possible FirstBits. By random trial and error I found that `1ijj1` is untaken. Is there a way to find the shortest possible untaken FirstBits? (So I can generate it using vanitygen)

Comment: If I was an evil person I'd generate `1ijj1` it myself just for the lulz.

Comment: According to [this post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=22785.msg949105#msg949105) all of the 4 character firstbits are taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a solution, it is brute-force. Make a loop and add variable characters, test them one by one. Start with one variable characters, try all combinations, add another variable character, try all combinations, rinse, repeat until you find unused firstbits.

Comment: Okay... But how do I check if a given firstbits is used?

Comment: If I wanted to do it I'd plug into the blockchain API somehow and script the search. If you're going to do a brute-force search you'll have to script it anyway.

Comment: @David, that seems rather hard on the firstbits website, given that you'd need 5 million requests (ish) to fully search for 5 character firstbits.

Comment: Hmm. Is there some kind of database I can download of firstbits that I can search through?

Comment: @lurfjurv Download, probably not. However, you can use a program called Abe to make a firstbit database. I wrote [a guide](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5519/2306) about setting up Abe back in November, which I just updated to cover the firstbits feature.