# How to parse the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I know there are websites providing blockchain information, but I want to write some script to explore the blockchain on my own. How do I do it? Are there any document available online?

Comment: I wrote a guide about setting up bitcoin-abe a while back. Maybe you'll find it useful. [Link](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/how-do-i-access-information-on-blockexplorer-com-or-blockchain-info-without-issu/5519#5519)

Comment: Thanks. I will do an upvote in words as I don't have that privilege to upvote comments yet...

Comment: @NickODell The link you gave was on Ubuntu, does it work with Mac OS X?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have a mac to try it on. If you do go this path, please let me know so I can update my guide!

Answer (score 1):

Not much documentation, but you can look at how others are doing it by examining their code. Take a look at [bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/jtobey/bitcoin-abe). It is pretty straightforward.