# How to install Abe?

Tags: block

I've downloaded [Abe](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) and ran python "*setup.py install*". There were no errors. But what's next? I didn't find any guidelines on how to run Abe in [README](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe).

Comment: I wrote a guide to install this here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5519/2306

Answer (score 1):

The "Web server" section of the README explains this briefly:

> By default, Abe expects to be run in a FastCGI environment. For an overview of FastCGI setup, see README-FASTCGI.txt.
>
> To run the built-in HTTP server instead of FastCGI, specify a TCP port and network interface in abe.conf, e.g.:
>
> ```
> port 2750
> host 127.0.0.1  # or a domain name
> ```

For personal use, you probably won't want to set up a FastCGI environment (unless you already have one set up). So, you can use the built-in HTTP server using the configuration above. In the above configuration, to talk to Abe you would go to the following URL in your browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:2750
```

If all goes well, you should see the Abe interface.

Answer (score 1):

To start doing some cool things with this project I suggest you to check out the
[README-MYSQL.txt](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe/blob/master/README-MYSQL.txt)

After installing all the proper requisites, modify your `abe-my.conf` to your server settings.

Then in step #7 it says initial data load. Witch, should take a couple of DAYS.

After those steps you can start your web server.

As Greg said, FastCGI is cool option as well. Though, I believe that it is more directed towards python developers. If you are a php guy like me, I would just make my custom applications connect directly to the MySQL database.

I would love to use FastCGI so that I can commit some cool scripts on this project. But, as I am a PHP developer, I rather make the use of Abe as a separate program that interacts with the db and having my APP to deal with that info.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [toshi](https://toshi.io/), for my project it worked better than abe.