# Getting all transactions that ever occurred for a bitcoin address

Tags: transactions, address

I know you can use various APIs to get the balance for a given bitcoin address, but is there a way to total all the bitcoin that were ever received at a given address?

A so-called "transaction history" for a given address?

Answer (score 2):

[BlockTrail's address API](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs#api_address) will do what you're looking for.

Calling URL:

```
https://api.blocktrail.com/v1/btc/address/1NcXPMRaanz43b1kokpPuYDdk6GGDvxT2T?api_key=MY_APIKEY
```

Result:

```
{
    "address": "1NcXPMRaanz43b1kokpPuYDdk6GGDvxT2T",
    "hash160": "ED12908714FFD43142BF9832692017E8AD54E9A8",
    "balance": 49497392,
    "received": 115015000,
    "sent": 65517608,
    "unconfirmed_received": 0,
    "unconfirmed_sent": 0,
    "unconfirmed_transactions": 0,
    "total_transactions_in": 4,
    "total_transactions_out": 10,
    "category": "donations",
    "tag": "blocktrail"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin-Abe can do this, and I wrote a guide on installing it [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/how-do-i-access-information-on-blockexplorer-com-or-blockchain-info-without-issu/5519#5519).

Once you have it installed, issue a `getrecievedbyaddress` request.