# How is UTXO tracked?

Tags: blockchain, utxo

What is the best way to compute UTXO of any address? Do I have to traverse whole block chain each time? Is there a efficient way to compute it?

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to index the UTXO set efficiently?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/30884/5406)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse blockchain only once and save **all** utxo into database. I am not sure that it is **best way** because I do not know the target of your efforts