# How to get balance of tens of thousands of addresses?

Tags: address, balance, ruby

What is the best way to get balance of large amount of addresses?
I tried to use APIs from different providers, but they are limiting the requests. Is there any APIs that give premium service without limiting requests?

Or maybe should I run full node, and use it?
If yes, how I'm using the full node to get the addresses balances? I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to index the UTXO set efficiently?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/how-to-index-the-utxo-set-efficiently)

Answer (score 4):

I think your should consider that using an API could result in fakes, wrongly-validated data. Using an API means you fully trust the API service,... which is kind-of against bitcoin no-trust model.

I recommend you to run a full node (Bitcoin Core 0.13.2 during time of writing).

There is no address-index (there is a patch you can manually compile into Core).

Simplest way with standard Bitcoin-Core 0.13.2 is to import all your addresses as **watch-only** into a wallet.

### import addresses

Use the RPC call `importaddress <address> "" false` to import a watch only address.

The 3rd argument `false` is required to not rescan the blockchain for each import (can take serval hours).

Once you have imported all addresses, stop bitcoind/qt and restart it with the startup argument `-rescan`.

The rescan may take a couple of minutes/hours (depending on your Disk/RAM/CPU). Once done, you can call `getreceivedbyaddress <addr>` for each address to get the balance.

**This result in authentic, self-validated data.**

**Note:** If you are using Bitcoin Core 0.14, consider importing multiple addresses with `importmulti`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this method is not very effective if the addresses list change every run, because each run I need to go through this process that can take some time. If I'm running full node, I should have access to all data on the blockchain, no? No convenient way to access this data?

Comment: Then you need an address index. Either look at the existing Core patches (There is a pull request for Bitcoin Core) or try to use existing alternatives (Bitpays Insight [based on Bitcoin Core])

Comment: Thanks! I tried to search for solution for my question, but I didn't find any. I think this solution should be added to Bitcoin Core official documentation/wiki.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [blockonomics api](https://www.blockonomics.co/views/api.html) . Their free plans allow 50 addresses at once and paid one [upto 8000](https://www.blockonomics.co/views/faqs.html#merchant-queries)

If you want to run your own node. I would recommend running [abe blockexplorer](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) along with your node. Core wallet and other SPV wallets like electrum have known to become sluggish with [large number of addresses](https://www.blockonomics.co/views/faqs.html#merchant-queries)