# Setting up Bitcoin Abe?

Tags: bitcoind, abe

I've followed the tutorial provided in this answer:

[How do I access information on blockexplorer.com or blockchain.info without issuing requests to those websites?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/how-do-i-access-information-on-blockexplorer-com-or-blockchain-info-without-issu/5519#5519)

But there aren't any instructions on how to get and run bitcoind first as Abe requires the genesis blocks.

In addition, I am getting the following error when trying to synchronize:

```
$ python -m Abe.abe --config=abe-sqlite.conf --commit-bytes 100000 --no-serve

failed to load /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf'
catch_up_rpc: abort
```

I have bitcoind installed on my ubuntu server:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bitcoind
$ bitcoind
```

What should I put in my config file? What else does Abe require from bitcoind?